# Make circle big while preserving circle like shape (css)

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

so I have a circle in html and css, and it looks like when I make it too big, it starts becoming a weird blob.
How would I make it big, and yet still preserve the circle like shape?

Thanks!

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/bUqNA/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id = "circle"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#circle{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: [Use a `border-radius: 50%`](http://jsfiddle.net/bUqNA/7/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `border-radius` to `150px`

```
#circle{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

The radius should be the half of the width or height . Also both the height and width should be equal

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bUqNA/6/)

Otherwise you can put `border-radius` as 50% , border radius is directly correlated with the elements width.

```
#circle{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bUqNA/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Use border-radius ad 50%. If you want a bigger circle then increase the width and height of the div in pixels. However make sure the width and height is same. It should always be square shaped